# How to reuse sub-query when the number of reuses is not the complete list of columns in main query?

Tags: sql, sql-server

So the question is:

```
select

column1,
column2,
(select column_x from anotherTable with conditionsDerived) as column3,
(select column_y from anotherTable with conditionsDerived) as column4

from mainTable
where conditions;
```

In the above example, for columns column3 and column4, the same query is being used twice. I believe it takes twice the time and I want to avoid that. I know how to handle it if column1 and column2 were not there. Important point is conditionsDerived is based on the current query from mainTable, that is it is not a standalone query. It depends on at least one column of mainTable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that your queries are really correlated subqueries.  If that is the case, then you can use a "lateral join".  In SQL Server this is accomplished using `outer apply`:

```
select t.column1, t.column2,
       an.column_x as column3, an.column_y as column4
from mainTable t outer apply
     (select column_x, column_y
      from anothertable an
      where . . .
     ) an
where conditions;
```

`Apply` is like having a correlated subquery in the `from` clause.  But it is better . . . the subquery can return multiple columns and/or multiple rows.

If the query is not correlated, you can still use `apply`.  But you could also use `cross join` as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a WITH clause which could improve the performance and make more readable code.

This articles can help you:

https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/with-clause

http://modern-sql.com/feature/with

Comment: Why would you post a like for Oracle when the OP indicates that he was using MS SQL Server?

Comment: I put it as a reference of the advantages of WITH and examples on how to use it, as WITH clause is part of SQL:1999 standard is also available in SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

Use a STD join query:

```
select     table1.id,
           table1.column_1,
           table1.column_2,
           table2.column_3,
           table2.column_4
from       table1
inner join table2
on         table1.id = table2.id
where      table2.field_x = table2.conditions
and        table1.field_y = table1.conditions;
```